# HttpContext in WCF

Tags: wcf

To use httpContext I changed app.config  and added `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">` inside `<system.serviceModel>`.

I also added `using System.Web` to my implementation class.

Problem is, httpcontext is not available in my implementation class after doing the required steps.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See here: [WCF Services and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

> Within an AppDomain, features
>   implemented by the HTTP runtime apply
>   to ASP.NET content but not to WCF.
>   Many HTTP-specific features of the
>   ASP.NET application platform do not
>   apply to WCF Services hosted inside of
>   an AppDomain that contains ASP.NET
>   content. Examples of these features
>   include the following:
>
> **HttpContext: Current is always null**
>   when accessed from within a WCF
>   service. **Use RequestContext instead.**

Comment: I see some example which say that we can use httpcontext.current if we set AspNetCompatibility to true in app.config.

Comment: Sure, but if you really want to do that (see Aliostad answer on this), but I bet there are some reasons why it's not enabled by default.

Comment: and I want to know why it is not enabled. still facing problem :-(

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to access `HttpContext` in WCF **if you set** `AspNetCompatibility` in web.config and on the Service Implementation.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx).

Comment: AspNetCompatibility it is set to true in my app.config. i mentioned it in my question but i think something went wrong when i post the question.

Comment: See my link. You also need `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
                       AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]`

Comment: ok I set AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)] but still httpcontext is not available. :-(

Comment: Are you running IIS 7 and .NET 4?

Comment: I am running IIS 5.1 i guess and .NET 3.5.
I can use httpcontext in my normal ASP.Net application, but in my WCF service I am not able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use OperationContext? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx