# Calling Entity Framework db context from WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

We have developed an ASP Net MVC application using the Repository pattern. 
We are creating a db context instance by using a context provider class like:

```
public class ContextProvider

        public static DBEntities GetContext()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Items["_EntityContext"] as DBEntities;
        }
    }
```

Here we are making sure that the DBEntities db call exists only during the existence of the request - we are putting an instance into a Session map - `HttpContext.Current.Items["_EntityContext"]` in this example.

We are using this in our entire Asp Net Mvc Project as following:

```
public class TeamRepository
{
    #region Members

    private DBEntities storeDB = null;

    #endregion Members

    #region Constructors

    public TeamRepository()
    {
        storeDB = ContextProvider.GetContext();

    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Methods
```

...

Now we need to create a WCF service to enable access to some features to other vendors.

Since all the Repository classes are a part of a project - they were not excluded to a separated DLL I made a reference to the entire project in my new WCF project so that I could use already existing DB Repository method calls.

Here I am facing an issue since I am not able to access to the Session variable `HttpContext.Current.Items["_EntityContext"]` - method call public static DBEntities `GetContext()` is always returning null when called from WCF Service.

I tried to make `HttpContext.Current` Available Within a WCF Service available by placing

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

on my Service class,
and tweaking the serviceHostingEnvironment section of web.config, which now looks like this:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://localhost” />
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

but with no results.

I am using Windows 10.

Do you know a way I can access `HttpContext.Current.Items["_EntityContext"]`... contained within Asp Net Mvc project from my WCF Project?

Regards

Comment: The architectural answer would be to use Dependency Injection, and thereby remove any http.* type references in your repositories.

Comment: There is no HTTPContext in WCF, WCF session is different from the HTTP session. Official explanation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Here are some pertinent discussions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637749/c-sharp-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-pro
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990479/httpcontext-in-wcf

Comment: You have this post that gives some instructions how it may be used: https://dylanbeattie.net/2011/02/24/making-httpcontextcurrent-available.html - this says that it can be accessed...

Comment: Here, also says it can be used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904313/access-httpcontext-current-from-wcf-web-service/5904345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved using the following steps:
I decorated my service implementation with the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService {
   . . .
}
```

The last thing I had to do was necessitated by WCF not supporting multiple host headers; I had to hard-wire the WCF endpoint to listen on a specific hostname. In this case, this involved tweaking the serviceHostingEnvironment section of web.config, which now looks like this:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix=http://services.mydomain.com” />
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

And then adding another attribute to the service implementation class and initializing the HttpContext.Current.Items session:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService {
HttpContext.Current.Items["_EntityContext"] = new DBEntities();
...
}
```